# SMTP library demo on LiveCode

Tags: smtp, gmail, livecode

I'm trying to build a mobile app that when user presses a button, it sends emails direct to an email address. I found that Sarah's SMTP library demo do this.  I try to put on the server the `smtp.gmail.com` but Iv'e got this error:

```
> 5.7.0 must issue a starttls command first
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that smtp.gmail.com uses SSL. Sarah's library doesn't do this. You need to authenticate with your correct Gmail user name and password and you might want to try executing the LiveCode syntax

```
libUrlSetSSLVerification false
```

You need to do this before you start using Sarah's lib. I wonder if you also need to fiddle with the default headers. For this, you need to edit the script of the lib.

Answer (score 1):

The server you are connecting to requires you to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sarah's library require sockets?  So on IOS (until sockets support is complete with the new changes) I think you would have to use the rresockets external and adjust sarahs library to use the externals functionality rather than LC sockets.

For android, also no sockets and no rresockets either, though these will hopefully be implemented before too long.

A workaround would be to have an email sending script on a web server, post the data to the right address and have the script send the email.

Of course for desktop sockets are available so sarahs should work fine for that (as per the other suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

This page has a sample SMTP stack.  I haven't tested it yet, but people have said it works,just have to make sure ports are set up.

http://www2.altuit.com/webs/altuit2/RunRev/Downloads.htm